# BBox <g> элементов в вычислении svg

Tags: javascript, svg, анимация

Я только что натолкнулся на странный случай вычисления позиций подпрыгивающей коробки и, похоже, я еще не понял причины этого.

Прежде всего, `bounding box` определяется как самый близко прилегающий прямоугольник, в который может быть заключен не трансформированный элемент.

У меня всегда было впечатление, что для групп это означает, что в основном это `bounding box` всех детей группы.

Однако сегодня я наткнулся на это:

`<g id="outer">
  <g id="inner" transform="translate(100, 100)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
  </g>
</g>`

`bounding boxes` (границы) элементов следующие:

`rect:   x: 0,   y: 0,   w: 100, h: 100`
`#inner: x: 0,   y: 0,   w: 100, h: 100`
`#outer: x: 100, y: 100, w: 100, h: 100`

Я ожидал, что все блоки одинаковы, но, как вы можете видеть, внешний блок НЕ является объединением внутренних элементов (в этом случае он будет равен `bbox` `#inner`).

Вместо этого он принимает значение преобразование внутренних элементов.
Итак, правильно ли говорить, что `bbox` группы является объединением трансформированных `bbox` ее дочерних элементов?

Или, если говорить более программно, объединение всех вызовов `getBoundingClientRect` (при условии, что `scroll` равен 0, так как `getBoundingClientRect` игнорирует `scroll`)?

Был бы очень признателен за ссылку, указывающую мне на правильную часть спецификации.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53775530/7394871

Answer (score 2):

В этой демонстрации красный многоугольник представляет `#outer BBox` во время анимации, в которой вращается чёрный прямоугольник.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
let o = outer.getBBox()
let i = inner.getBBox()

let BBpoly = drawBBox(o); 



function drawBBox(bb){
  let p = [{x:bb.x,y:bb.y},
           {x:bb.x+bb.width,y:bb.y},
           {x:bb.x+bb.width,y:bb.y+bb.height},
           {x:bb.x,y:bb.y+bb.height}];
  let BBpoly = drawPolygon(p, BBoxes);
  return BBpoly;
}


function drawPolygon(p, parent) {
  let poly = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'polygon');
  let ry = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    ry.push(String(p[i].x + ", " + p[i].y));
  }
  var points = ry.join(" ");
  poly.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', points);

  parent.appendChild(poly);
  return poly;
}


function updatePolygon(p,poly){
  let ry = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    ry.push(String(p[i].x + ", " + p[i].y));
  }
  var points = ry.join(" ");
  poly.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', points);
}

let a = 0;
function Frame(){
  requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  inner.setAttributeNS(null,"transform", `rotate(${a}, 120,120)`)
  let bb = outer.getBBox()
  let p = [{x:bb.x,y:bb.y},
           {x:bb.x+bb.width,y:bb.y},
           {x:bb.x+bb.width,y:bb.y+bb.height},
           {x:bb.x,y:bb.y+bb.height}];
  updatePolygon(p,BBpoly);
  
  a++
}

Frame()
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:300px;}
polygon{fill:none; stroke:red; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 250">
  <g id="BBoxes"></g>
  <g id="outer">
  <g id="inner">
    <rect x="70" y="70" width="100" height="100"  />
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```